# Iterative Thresholding - The Low-rank component derivation

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to understand the derivation of iterative thresholding from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5055). A convex problem defined as,
$$\min_{A,E}||A||_*+\lambda||E||_1+\frac{1}{2\tau}||A||^2_F+\frac{1}{2\tau}||E||^2_F\quad\text{s.t. }D=A+E$$
which can be reformulate as Lagrange function,
$$\mathcal{L}(Y,A,E)= ||A||_*+\lambda||E||_1+\frac{1}{2\tau}||A||^2_F+\frac{1}{2\tau}||E||^2_F+\frac{1}{\tau}\langle Y,D-A-E \rangle$$
I will focus on the $A$ component (the low rank), which a well-known analysis shows that,
$$U\mathcal{S}_\epsilon[S]V^H=\text{arg}\min_{X}||X||_*+||X-W||^2_F$$
where, $USV^H$ is the SVD of $W$. My understanding is that I have to reform the Lagrange function into the well-known form, which leads to,
$$||L-Y||^2_F =||A||^2+\langle Y,D-A-E \rangle$$
I'm still unable to prove this, is it the correct way to implement it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure which line you're asking about. Are you trying to understand how to get to the third equation from the second equation? Either way, you might want to look at the references [7,24] and see if they have any useful insights.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm a bit confuse on how the inner product associated into the squared of the frobenius norm. A source for learning would be very helpful..

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. Can you tell me which Frobenius norm you understand, and which inner product it is associated with? What is $L$ in your last equation? Unfortunately, I don't have any textbooks I can recommend, although you might want to look at "sparse principal component analysis".

Comment: I'm so sorry for the late reply @1Rock and thanks for the help! The thing I confused about is the association between dot product and the Frobenius norm. In some paper somehow the dot product was merged into the Frobenius norm and I couldn't figure out the explanation. I'll probably read some Linear Algebra book to understand it.

Comment: Good luck! I hope you've found an answer, but if you haven't, remember that $\|A-B\|_F^2=\|A\|_F^2 + \|B\|_F^2 - 2\langle A,B\rangle$.

Comment: @1Rock Yes, I found that too! Thank you for you reply!